# Creating Jquery bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Ok so I created this bar graph with jquery and I'm trying to display it on my website. I tested this in CodePen and it worked, but when I copy the code into my website its not working.

I am linking to the jquery library in my header which I have as:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js

Now my problem is the .bar is not displaying and animating but everything else like the border, labels and everything else are but not the graphs. Can someone help me out?

My HTML is below:

```
<div id="chart">
          <ul id="skill">
            <li><span>Proficient</span></li>
            <li><span>Above Average</span></li>
            <li><span>Average</span></li>
            <li><span>Basic</span></li>
          </ul>

          <ul id="bars">
            <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Graphic Design</span></li>
            <li><div data-height="240" class="bar"></div><span>HTML 5</span></li>
            <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>CSS / SASS</span></li>
            <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Javascript & JQuery</span></li>
            <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>Content Management Systems (CMS)</span></li>
            <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>PHP</span>
            </li>
            <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>Videography</span>
            </li>
            <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Flash & ActionScript</span>
            </li>
            <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>3-D Animation & Pritning</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

SASS:

```
  #chart {
    width: 90%;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;

    #skill {
      width: 10%; 
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;

      li {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        height: 20px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
        margin: 40px 0;

        span {
          color: #d2f9c2;
        }
      }
    }

    #bars {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      height: 300px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 15px 0 0;
      float: right;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $background;

      li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;

        .bar {
          display: block;
          width: 60px;
          margin-left: 15px;
          background: linear-gradient(#d2f9c2, #379f53);
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
        }

        span {
          color: #eee;
          width: 202px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -7em;
          left: 1.5em;
          text-align: left;
          transform: rotate(40deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#bars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
    var height = $(this).data('height');

    $(this).animate({
      'height' : height 
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

please help?

Comment: Any errors in the console? BTW that's not plain CSS.

Comment: If it works in Codepen (link available?) but not on the server it seems unlikely that the code is the issue. Also, that's not CSS...it's a SASS (I think).

Comment: 1) Any error message in the console? 2) Why don't you use graph plugins like ChartJS, it supports bar graphs?

Comment: I didnt want to use a plugin because i wanted build it from scratch (sorta).. and why rely so heavily on plugin seriously what am i learning about php, jquery, and everything by always using plugins. Id like to learn the stuff so i can do things myself occasionally

Answer (score -1):

I got this to work. Thanks all for your feed back. I ended up placing the JQuery at the wrong area of my code.

My code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Experience Page */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<!--<div class="main">-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="experience">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="graph">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="chart">
              <ul id="skill">
                <li><span>Proficient</span></li>
                <li><span>Above Average</span></li>
                <li><span>Average</span></li>
                <li><span>Basic</span></li>
              </ul>

              <ul id="bars">
                <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Graphic Design</span></li>
                <li><div data-height="240" class="bar"></div><span>HTML 5</span></li>
                <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>CSS / SASS</span></li>
                <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Javascript & JQuery</span></li>
                <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>Content Management Systems (CMS)</span></li>
                <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>PHP</span>
                </li>
                <li><div data-height="180" class="bar"></div><span>Videography</span>
                </li>
                <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>Flash & ActionScript</span>
                </li>
                <li><div data-height="120" class="bar"></div><span>3-D Animation & Pritning</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="projects">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'projects_position' ); ?>
    </div>
</div> <!--.main-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#bars li .bar").each( function( key, bar ) {
        var height = $(this).data('height');

        $(this).animate({
          'height' : height 
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
</script>
```

SASS:

```
.experience {


height: 350px;
}

.graph {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: $darkgrey;

  #chart {
    width: 90%;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: block;

    #skill {
      width: 10%; 
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;

      li {
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        height: 20px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #c7c7c7;
        margin: 40px 0;

        span {
          color: #d2f9c2;
          font-size: 1.2em;
          font-weight: 600;
        }
      }
    }

    #bars {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      height: 300px;
      padding: 0;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $background;

      li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;

        .bar {
          display: block;
          width: 60px;
          margin-left: 15px;
          background: linear-gradient(#d2f9c2, #379f53);
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
        }

        span {
          color: #eee;
          width: 202px;
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -7em;
          left: 1.5em;
          text-align: left;
          transform: rotate(40deg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```